# Deploying Metaflow on AWS results in a "403 Forbidden" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, netflix-metaflow

I used the CloudFormation template provided by Metaflow to deploy it on AWS, and I ran `metaflow configure aws` to create a configuration file with the deployment outputs, as outlined [in the documentation](https://admin-docs.metaflow.org/metaflow-on-aws/deployment-guide/aws-cloudformation-deployment). The deployment was successful and the configuration file is clearly being read, but when I run a simple flow involving a @batch decorator, I get the following error (this is after Metaflow reports the graph is good and Pylint is happy):

```
Metadata request (/flows/MyFlow) failed (code 403): {"message":"Forbidden"}
```

Does anyone know the reason for this error?

[Digging into the code](https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow/blob/5186c6c5bba36d9e77077413ee2495dc79da3dca/metaflow/plugins/metadata/service.py), it looks like this occurs when an API query to the `METAFLOW_SERVICE_URL` is made. Unfortunately, I don't know what the purpose of this query is or what authentication it expects.

This has failed for two users, one of whom was the one to actually run the CloudFormation deployment successfully, so whatever permission is needed, it is not straightforwardly related to the permission needed to deploy.

Comment: Solved - it turns out the value shown in the CloudFormation outputs for METAFLOW_SERVICE_AUTH_KEY is not the auth key itself, it is the API key needed to get the auth key. Running `aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key <YOUR_KEY_ID_FROM_CFN> --include-value | grep value` as suggested produces the actual key and fixes the permissions issue.

Comment: For me only the aws console worked. Strangely, the command line api did not find the api-key. But the comment from @Jack Holland gave me the idea for the solution. From the official docs:
>>>From the AWS Console, navigate to Services and select API Gateway from Networking & Content Delivery (or search for it in the search bar). Click on your API, select API Keys from the left side, select the API that corresponds to your Stack name, and click show next to API Key.<<<